# LINQ EF QUERY (view difference from condition & dynamic)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I need to make a query to filter records, when get distinct records, get these records information by difference conditions. Also I need these to be dynamic(quantity filter in first select)

Let me show you an example:

I have 2 tables:

**tblCustomers:**

```
id    customerName  
1        John  
2        Philip  
3        Steve
```

**tblOrders**

```
id    customerId     ordId    payment
1      1              100      True
2      1              101      True
3      1              102      False 
4      2              101      True
5      2              102      True
6      2              103      False 
7      3              101      True
```

My condition is:

```
where (orderId = 101 and orderId = 102)
```

but get all records of this customer that `payment = true` I mean my condition is different from what I need to see.

I want to receive all records with `payment=True` without care of orderId

I must get:

```
john    100
john    101  
Philip  101
Philip  102
```

Clearing: I need two step - first filter customer who has orderId=101&102, in second step i want to show these selected customers' orderId which payment is true. so for example in first step i get john(who has order id =101&102) then show john 100 - john 101 (which payment istrue). consider tblorder.id=1 isn't in first query but I must show in final result.

@Raphael direct me to better expression:I want to see all payment true order for the customers that have orders (101 & 102). but orderids may be more than 2 (thanks @Raphael).

**2nd problem is:** it must be dynamic. Sometimes I have more than 10 orderId that must be checked - sometimes less. I mean my query must be flexible.

In SQL Server select command, I can prepare a string variable and use but in linq I can't do it.

Comment: Hi mohammad, I'm not sure if I understood your question. You want all order with id equals to 101 or 102 that have payment set to true? or you want just all the records that have payment set to true?

Comment: @Raphael, thank you in fact i need first every person who has orderId=101&102, but show records that contain payment=true of result of previous step. let me clearing my question(edit it).

Comment: @Raphael, please check clearing part that i added. thanks.

Comment: Ok now I got it, you what to se all payment true order for the customers that have orders (101 & 102).

Comment: yes you summarize better than me!

Comment: I'm better with linq with lambda expression, bit I try to write you an example hoping it will work ;)

Comment: @Raphael, thank you. but why nobody else answer me?

Comment: Ok I see that serv has almost found the solution. I let him finish the job :P, good luck with your query

Comment: @Raphael, i got serv solution. do you have better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
        new Customer { Id = 2, Name = "Philip" },
        new Customer { Id = 3, Name = "Steve" }
    };

    List<Order> orders = new List<Order>
    {
        new Order { Id = 1, CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 100, Payment = true },
        new Order { Id = 2, CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 101, Payment = true },
        new Order { Id = 3, CustomerId = 1, OrderId = 102, Payment = false },
        new Order { Id = 4, CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 101, Payment = true },
        new Order { Id = 5, CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 102, Payment = true },
        new Order { Id = 6, CustomerId = 2, OrderId = 103, Payment = false },
        new Order { Id = 7, CustomerId = 3, OrderId = 101, Payment = true }
    };

    List<int> orderIds = new List<int> { 101, 102 };

    var customersWithRelevantOrders =
        from ord in orders
        group ord by ord.CustomerId into customerOrders
        where orderIds.All (
            i => customerOrders.Select (co => co.OrderId).Contains(i))
        select customerOrders.Key;

    var paymentTrueOrdersForTheseCustomers =
        from ord in orders
        join cust in customers on ord.CustomerId equals cust.Id
        where ord.Payment
        where customersWithRelevantOrders.Contains(cust.Id)
        select new
        {
            Name = cust.Name,
            OrderId = ord.OrderId
        };
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public bool Payment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you, let me check it. i must convert it to vb.

Comment: i open a c# project, but in join give me error: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: Fixed two small errors (missing semicolon and 'h' in where). Otherwise I can copy this straight into LinqPad and it works.

Comment: yes. problem was in my table field type, vb didn't alarm me, but when shift to c# visual studio alarm me. anyway, i am trying to double check to put answered this post.

Comment: whould you check this link my problem is changed but nobody can help me, please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172863/linq-query-where-contains-list-of-class?noredirect=1#comment31875030_21172863

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your post and the comments, you need all customers, where the orderId is 101 or 102 and the payment is true.

You need the where clause with the orderIds to be dynamic so you can change the Ids to be checked against outside of the query.

```
List<int> IDList = new List<int>();
IDList.Add(101);
IDList.Add(102);
IDList.Add(110);
//...

var result = from cust in tblCustomers
             join order in tblOrders on cust.id equals order.customerId
             where IDList.Contains(order.ordId) && order.payment == true
             select new {
                          Name = cust.customerName
                          OrderId = order.ordId
                          payment = order.payment
                          //...
                        }
```

With this you can store all orderIds which need to be checked against in a list, which in turn you can edit from your code.

**EDIT**
I really haven't found a clean solution to your problem, so I took a detour, which isn't very clean but should work. In my example I created 2 classes, `Customer` & `Order` and filled it with your data from above. Then I took my first query and attached a groupBy to it and a where-clause comparing the length of the grouping with the length of the list

```
var result = (from cust in Customers
             join order in Orders on cust.Id equals order.customerId
             where IDList.Contains(order.orderId) && 
                   order.payment == true 

             select new {
                         Name = cust.Name,
                         OrderId = order.orderId,
                         Payment = order.payment
                        //...
                        }).GroupBy (r => r.Name)
                          .Where (r => r.Count() == IDList.Count());
```

Output:

```
Name OrderId Payment
Philip 101   True 
Philip 102   True
```

If you want/need it, I can provide you with the whole Linqpad query, so you can see my whole code and what I have done. Speaking of Linqpad: ignore the result.Dump() line. It won't work on visual Studio.

Comment: "where the orderId is 101 or 102" is wrong, i want:"where the orderId is 101 AND 102". i don't togive who just has 101 for example.

Comment: Oh, let me just scratch that up in Linqpad. I guess we need a groupBy here, but I'll need some minutes to write and test. Just to confirm. Users with just 101 is wrong. Users with just 102 is wrong. You want users wo have 101 AND 102.

Comment: yes. you got what i need thank you. as i understood group by is just for counting! if you have some source to read direct me.

Comment: is it possible in linq?

Comment: I have edited in a, what I think is, working solution. Not very slick, but it should do the job. Lets hope the pros like Söner oder Tim hop by and improve it ;)

Comment: Your solution doesn'twork, that'swhy i ask in diffrent way. Message=Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IGrouping`2' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Comment: would you write in vb? i afraid make mistake in convert,dear serv: i am in bad situation, i work on a project over 2 before month and now can't make a report. but let me convert if i get any error inform you

Comment: I am afraid not. I could give the complete code I have written up in LinqPad, but I am not familiar with Vb.net

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,VB$AnonymousType_1`3[System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VB$AnonymousType_1`3[System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]]'.

Comment: Dim IDList = New List(Of String)(New String() {"101", "102"})

        Dim result = (From cust In cwContext.tblCustomers
         Join order In cwContext.tblOrders On cust.id Equals order.customerId
         Where IDList.Contains(order.orderId) And order.payment = "1"
         Select Name = cust.customerName, OrderId = order.orderId, Payment = order.payment).ToList()

        result = result.GroupBy(Function(r) r.Name).Where(Function(r) r.Count() = IDList.Count())

Comment: i omitted second result, and work but give wrong result, it give me rows that orderId="any of IDList" and payment=1

Comment: would you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655059/linq-relational-division, i make my question simple.