# linq query where contains list of class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table:

**tblFildsVal**
 - **id** bigint;
 - **listId** bigint;
 - **listFieldValue** bigint;
 - **parrentId** bigint;

Then I have an array (or List) representing 4 matching conditions:

**myArr**
 - **listId** //refer to listId
 - **rangeType**  //it has 4 vlaue: 1)exact 2)upper 3)lower 4)between
 - **from** //lower value
 - **to** //upper value

Multiple matching conditions can be chained together such that it performs a match on any record from **tblFildsVal** against any of the given set of conditions.

For example:

```
myArr{{1,1,100,Null},{2,2,125,Null},{3,3,Null,175},{4,4,125,175}}
```

It means I want to know *every* record (groupped by parrentId) where any of:

```
(1)listId == 1 && listFieldValue == 100  
(2)listId == 2 && listFieldValue > 125  
(3)listId == 3 && listFieldValue < 175  
(4)listId == 4 && (listFieldValue > 125 && listFieldValue < 175)
```

**(continue to rest of array)**

I tested (all) & (contains) when I had 1D array,

```
var q = from flds in tblFildsVal  
        group flds by flds.parrentId into gFields  
        where myArr.All(i => gFields.Select(co => co.listFieldValue).Contains(i))
```

but I have no idea in this case!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i can't write a query to get fields in tblFildsVal where meet myArr, please check "it means i want to know:"...

Comment: So your array specifies matching conditions, which you are checking against records of your table?  And you are looking for any records that match any of the given conditions?

Comment: @Mike Guthrie yes, in the example i explaind more.

Comment: @user2928818 I've updated the text to hopefully better fit your question. Please review, as I also corrected what I assume to be a logic error in your 3rd match condition in your example.

Comment: @Mike Guthrie yes it can be better, but up to now 4 people updated my question, but nobody answer it!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you need to implement your matching logic.  A simple All or Contains call will not satisfy the matching rules provided by your array.  I've implemented an example solution below that will show how you would need to write a query to check against the matching logic.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myMatchConditions = new int?[][]
            { 
                new int?[] { 1, 1, 100, null }, 
                new int?[] { 2, 2, 125, null }, 
                new int?[] { 3, 3, null, 175 }, 
                new int?[] { 4, 4, 125, 175 }
            };

        var myData = new MyTableItem[]
            {
                new MyTableItem { id = 1, listId = 1, listFieldValue = 150, parentId = 1 },
                new MyTableItem { id = 2, listId = 1, listFieldValue = 75, parentId = 1 },
                new MyTableItem { id = 3, listId = 2, listFieldValue = 150, parentId = 1 },
                new MyTableItem { id = 4, listId = 4, listFieldValue = 150, parentId = 1 },
                new MyTableItem { id = 5, listId = 5, listFieldValue = 150, parentId = 1 },
            };

        var matches = from d in myData
                      where myMatchConditions.Any(cond => (
                                (cond[0] == d.listId) && 
                                (cond[1] == 1 ? d.listFieldValue == cond[2] :
                                    (cond[1] == 2 ? d.listFieldValue > cond[2]  :
                                        (cond[1] == 3 ? d.listFieldValue < cond[3] :
                                            (cond[1] == 4 ? d.listFieldValue > cond[2] && d.listFieldValue < cond[3] : false)
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            ))
                      group d by d.parentId into g
                      select g;

    }

    class MyTableItem
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public long listId { get; set; }
        public long listFieldValue { get; set; }
        public long parentId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The important thing to note is the logic checking against the array.  Here, I've accomplished it by an Any call, and some nested ternary operators, which isn't a final solution that I'd recommend.

It could be made much more legible if you could explicitly create a class for your match conditions, then have some method like `bool MatchesMe(...)` which would check against each field, so that the logic for the matching could be separated visually from the LINQ statement.

Note: To get around restrictions working with the entity framework, you would either need to populate your match conditions to a table in the database, so you can then have records to use as objects in your matching logic; or, much simpler, you can get the results from the database table back as an IEnumerable, and then perform the matching logic much the same as in my example.

I would recommend creating a list of the `listId` parameters, so you are only pulling back database records that will need to be validated against the range condition.  So, for example, lets say you setup a `List<int> myListIdFilters` with the `listId` values from `myMatchConditions`. You would then make a change just to the first line of the logic check:

```cs
var matches = from d in myData.Where(myDataItem => myListIdFilters.Contains(myDataItem.listId)).AsEnumerable()
```

And the rest would remain the same.  The `AsEnumerable` call would cause the `IQueryable` object to be resolved, so the remainder of the logic would be performed outside of the EF (or LINQ to SQL) context.

Comment: let me check it, thank you for your reply anyway.

Comment: If he's using EF, then I think having the method extracted out like that would cause an exception...

Comment: +1 for even attempting to decipher this question as written

Comment: error: The LINQ expression node type ArrayIndex is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @Colin DeClue yes i am using EF, any idea?

Comment: @user2928818 How much did you do to [find out what that error means?](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+LINQ+expression+node+type+ArrayIndex+is+not+supported+in+LINQ+to+Entities) It is addressed well here on Stack Overflow. In short, though, it means you can use the array expressions, such as `cond[0]`, so you will indeed have to make the conditions into its own class, and invoke properties instead of array indices.

Comment: yes i put List<searchInfo> searchParameters = new List<searchInfo>();searchParameters.Add(new searchInfo(1, 1, 100, 125)); but get only primitive types ('such as int32, string, and Guid') are supported in this context