# EF LINQ query where meet all list or array

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have these data:

```
class MyTableItem
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long listId { get; set; }
    public long listFieldValue { get; set; }
    public long parentId { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
    var myData = new MyTableItem[]
        {
            new MyTableItem { id = 1, listId = 1, listFieldValue = 100, parentId = 1 },
            new MyTableItem { id = 2, listId = 2, listFieldValue = 130, parentId = 1 },
            new MyTableItem { id = 3, listId = 3, listFieldValue = 170, parentId = 1 },
            new MyTableItem { id = 4, listId = 4, listFieldValue = 170, parentId = 1 },

            new MyTableItem { id = 5, listId = 1, listFieldValue = 100, parentId = 2 },
            new MyTableItem { id = 6, listId = 2, listFieldValue = 130, parentId = 2 },
            new MyTableItem { id = 7, listId = 3, listFieldValue = 170, parentId = 2 },
            new MyTableItem { id = 8, listId = 4, listFieldValue = 270, parentId = 2 },
            ...(continue)
        };

    var myMatchConditions = new int?[][] //id, rangeTypeId(equal, more, less, between), from, to 
        { 
            new int?[] { 1, 1, 100, null }, 
            new int?[] { 2, 2, 125, null }, 
            new int?[] { 3, 3, null, 175 }, 
            new int?[] { 4, 4, 130, 180 }
            ...(can continue more)
        };
```

now i need to know which myData (groupBy parrentId) are matched by my conditions,
let me explain more:

I want to know which parrent Id has listFieldValue where:

1) (listId == 1)&&(listFieldValue == 100)
**and**
2) (listId == 2)&&(listFieldValue > 125)
**and**
3) (listId == 3)&&(listFieldValue < 175)
**and**
4) ((listId == 4)&&(listFieldValue > 130)&&(listFieldValue < 180))

**it must return (1)parrentId.**

Comment: Are you sure the first condition is `(listId == 1)&&(listFieldValue == 100)`, not `(listId == 1)&&(listFieldValue > 100)` ?

Comment: @ekad yes, i have 4 range type(equal, more, less, between) let me add in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There you go. Explanations are at the bottom:

```
IEnumurable<MyTableItem> temp = myData ;
for (int i = 0; i < myMatchConditions.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    var conditionType = myMatchConditions[i,1];
    if (conditionType == 1)
    {
        temp = temp.Where(_ => _listFieldValue == myMatchConditions[i,2]);
    }
    else
    {
        if (conditionType == 2 || conditionType == 4)
        {

            temp = temp.Where(_ => _listFieldValue > myMatchConditions[i,2]);
        }

        if (conditionType == 3 || conditionType == 4)
        {
            temp = temp.Where(_ => _listFieldValue < myMatchConditions[i,3]);
        }
    }
}
```

- I'm using `IEnumurable<MyTableItem>` which means it's Linq and not Linq to entities. I chose that because your `myData` is not an `EF` table but a simple array.
- I go through all the "rows" with a `for`, you can do that with a `foreach`, and I add the `Where` clauses to filter out more and more each time (The actual filtering will happen only when you use that `temp` list)
- I add a condition based on the type in the second cell, and if the type is 4... I add both the 2 and 3 type rules... which makes a 4 type rule

Comment: thnks, let me check it.

Comment: before i start test, in rel i use myData is EF table. it is an example, any thing change?

Comment: @mohammadadibi Yes. use `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`. That means that a query will generate and be sent to your DB.

Comment: how do i use it in query? i have(var q = from parent in myData group p  by myData.parentId into par where?

Comment: before now my search conditions was just 1D array of listfieldvalue, so i use: (var q = from parent in myData group p by myData.parentId into par where myMatchConditions.All(i => par.Select(co => co.parentId).Contains(i))

Comment: @mohammadadibi `temp.GroupBy(_ => _.parentId).ToList()`. the temp already holds all the conditions. What's left is to group the results and materialize them using `ToList` (or `ToArray`...)

Comment: before now my problem was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628505/linq-ef-query-view-difference-from-condition-dynamic, it solved, but now my query change to myMatchConditions that i explained.

Comment: @mohammadadibi i don't understand the last comment. But my answer still fits this current question.

Comment: I3arnon let me ask my question in different way in new post.